# html/css : weird border when clicking the button

Tags: html

my button has this weird border appearing when clicking on it.
how to remove it?
below is the html and image example

Buy Now

*Only While Supplies Last*

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)

Comment: No one appreciates your question, but I do.  Why for goodness sake, is a border or outline suddenly being generated the instant it's clicked.  Makes no sense and none of the answers address the issue.

Answer (score 6):

Just set your button outline to none:

```
input[type="button"]{
   outline:none;
}
input[type="button"]::-moz-focus-inner {
   border: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's just an outline. You can rid it out by using:

```
button: {
outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply fix this with css `outline` property, you need to remove the default `outline`

```
button {
   outline:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The outline property in CSS draws a line around the outside of an element. It's similar to border except that:

[Read outline properties](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_outline.asp)

[CSS tricks outline Property](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/outline/)

```
 button: {
    outline: none;
 }
```